# Page does not display errors after submitting the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and trying to play around with model, validations and controller.

I'm following some simple tutorial and have the following files:

Model:

```
public class ItineraryItem
{
    public DateTime? When { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MVCSuccinctly.Models.ItineraryItem
<h2>Create</h2>
<div class="editor">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.When) 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.When) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.When)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Duration)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>

    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class ItineraryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new ItineraryItem();
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

According to tutorial I entered values that are not valid for the data types in the model and submitted the form.

I'm supposed to get error messages for "When" and "Duration" fields, with the text for the validation message coming from the model binder, based on the datatypes, however, nothing happens.

Why is that?

Comment: You're expecting client-side validation?

Comment: If you're looking for server-side validation, you should also show us the controller action which accepts the form.

Comment: But  is not that enough to display errors if any? I'm following the tutorial which does not mention anything about the controller accepting the form. It just has the `Controller` with `Action`, `View` and `Model`. What else am I missing?

Comment: Typically, the contents of a form are submitted to the server via an additional http request. You have to supply the form with a url which typically corresponds to a controller action.

Comment: The tutorial may not be getting into that; in which case, they might want you to simply see client-side validation before anything gets submitted. To that end, make sure you're including something like jquery validation.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. I had to send my model to the Action and return just the View from there:

```
public ActionResult Create(ItineraryItem data)
{
    return View();
}
```